# Using selenium to select next page when URL is the same (Scraping)

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this website: http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/

So far I've used selenium to execute the javascript and get the table scraped. However, my code right now only gets me the first page. I was wondering if there's a way to access the other 17 pages, because when I click on next page the URL does not change, so I cannot just iterate over a different URL each time

Below is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def scrape():
    url = 'http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/'
    d={}
    f = open('east.txt','a')
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    lst = [x for x in range(0,25)]
    htmlsource = driver.page_source
    bs = BeautifulSoup(htmlsource)
    heading = bs.find_all('thead')[0]
    hlist = []
    for header in heading.find_all('tr'):
        head = header.find_all('th')
    for i in lst:
        if i!=2:
            hlist.append(head[i].get_text().strip())
    h = '|'.join(hlist)
    print h
    table = bs.find_all('tbody')[0]
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        d[cells[0].get_text()]=[y.get_text() for y in cells]
    for key in d:
        ret=[]
        for i in lst:
            if i != 2:
                ret.append(d.get(key)[i])
        s = '|'.join(ret)
        print s     

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    scrape()
```

Or is it possible for me to click next through the browser if I use webdriver.Chrome() instead of PhantomJS and then the Python run on the new page, after I click each time?